# Adding errorbars to 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I can't find a way to draw errorbars in a 3D scatter plot in matplotlib.
Basically, for the following piece of code

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(1)
ax.scatter(X, Y, zs = Z, zdir = 'z')
```

I am looking for something like

```
ax.errorbar(X,Y, zs = Z, dY, dX, zserr = dZ)
```

Is there a way to do this in mplot3d? If not, are there other libraries with this function?

Comment: I think you'd have to draw little lines around each point yourself, or try to get the 3D quiver to draw the error bars

Comment: That's certainly a workaround, I'll keep it in mind as a last resort.

Comment: Well worth getting in touch on the matplotlib forums, there may be such functionality already in development. If not, and you make a reasonable workaround, I'm sure they would be pleased to hear from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing the method for `matplotlib`: [official example for 3D errorbars](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/mplot3d/errorbar3d.html):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

# setting up a parametric curve
t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi+.1, 0.01)
x, y, z = np.sin(t), np.cos(3*t), np.sin(5*t)

estep = 15
i = np.arange(t.size)
zuplims = (i % estep == 0) & (i // estep % 3 == 0)
zlolims = (i % estep == 0) & (i // estep % 3 == 2)

ax.errorbar(x, y, z, 0.2, zuplims=zuplims, zlolims=zlolims, errorevery=estep)

ax.set_xlabel("X label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y label")
ax.set_zlabel("Z label")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

There is clearly example on forum http://mple.m-artwork.eu/home/posts/simple3dplotwith3derrorbars

Here is the code but is not built-in functionality:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')



#data
fx = [0.673574075,0.727952994,0.6746285]
fy = [0.331657721,0.447817839,0.37733386]
fz = [18.13629648,8.620699842,9.807536512]

#error data
xerror = [0.041504064,0.02402152,0.059383144]
yerror = [0.015649804,0.12643117,0.068676131]
zerror = [3.677693713,1.345712547,0.724095592]

#plot points
ax.plot(fx, fy, fz, linestyle="None", marker="o")

#plot errorbars
for i in np.arange(0, len(fx)):
    ax.plot([fx[i]+xerror[i], fx[i]-xerror[i]], [fy[i], fy[i]], [fz[i], fz[i]], marker="_")
    ax.plot([fx[i], fx[i]], [fy[i]+yerror[i], fy[i]-yerror[i]], [fz[i], fz[i]], marker="_")
    ax.plot([fx[i], fx[i]], [fy[i], fy[i]], [fz[i]+zerror[i], fz[i]-zerror[i]], marker="_")

#configure axes
ax.set_xlim3d(0.55, 0.8)
ax.set_ylim3d(0.2, 0.5)
ax.set_zlim3d(8, 19)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeap, drawing the errorbars this way still seems to be the only way to do this. It's a very neat example, I'll mark it as accepted.